# ExtractAssociatedIcon - In PowerShell ISE Work's fine, But in Console Doesn't Work

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a Powershell Script, Which Contains:

```
$Path = 'c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe'
$Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($Path)

$Icon.ToBitmap().Save('C:\icon.png')
```

I write those script in the '**PwerShell ISE**' when I run, it work's fine, and not problem show's up.

[image]

**But** when saving those script, and run by right click on '**icon.ps1**' then '**Run With PowerShell**' it will get this error:

```
PS D:\My PowerShell\tmp> .\icon.ps1
Unable to find type [System.Drawing.Icon].
At D:\My PowerShell\tmp\icon.ps1:2 char:9
+ $Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($Path)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Drawing.Icon:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\My PowerShell\tmp\icon.ps1:4 char:1
+ $Icon.ToBitmap().Save('C:\icon.png')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing`

Comment: @ PetSerAl, putting it in where?

Comment: @Aso: Clearly before you try to use `System.Drawing.Icon`, no? Think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the System.Drawing assembly before you run the rest of the script. At the beginning of the script, put this line:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
```

This will load the assembly first, allowing the rest of the script to access the methods and members of that assembly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7.1